# Why doesn't this function print to screen when called in a loop?

Tags: r

Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

```
test<-c(1,2,3,4)

adding<-function(file){
    file2<- file + 1
    return(file2)
}
```

yields upon calling:

```
> adding(file = 1)
[1] 2
```

but when I try:

```
for(number in test){
    adding(number)
    print(number)
}
```

I get:

```
> for(number in test){
+     adding(number)
+     print(number)
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
```

when I would've expected:

```
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 4
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 4
```

I'm using this basis for another `for loop` that I'm working on and wondering why it's not behaving as I expect.

Comment: you are printing the number  and not the results obtained from the adding function
try 

    `for(number in test){
        number1=adding(number);
        print(number1)
    }` but still this also will not give that output

Comment: Btw., you can simply do `adding(test)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opt for

```
for(number in test){
    print(adding(number))
    print(number)
}
```

to have your expected behavior, else `adding` per se won't print to screen.

Comment: I didn't think you needed to actually print anything - I'm not sure how the return function works without for loops... I want to use a for loop to iterate through each value in a vector, and with each iteration, evaluate the value as an argument to the function - I'm having trouble coming up with a reproducible example, though

Answer (score 2):

Your example works exactly as expected. You never explicitly printed the return value from the function call in the loop. Automatic printing is turned off in loops.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result of the function applied to each element of the vector as a vector itself, then

```
purrr::map_dbl(test, adding)
## [1] 2 3 4 5
```

or

```
sapply(test, adding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing something to screen without a `print` statement only happens in an interactive environment and only if you are inside out most [scopes](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/environment-scope). The variables inside the function have their own scope and those variables are not printed.

Food for though: This is for example different in MATLAB, where the result of every statement *not* ending with `;` is printed. In Python an additional requirement is that such a statement is executed alone. So executing two statements will not print anything, even if the last one is something that might be printed.